# cannot set height of table in html

Tags: html

I am making a simple table with the following html

```html
<table style="border-color:black;" bgcolor="white" border="3" width="40%" height="140"/>
```

The table height does change when I set it like this, however, when Ｉ set the height in percentage, it doesn't work.
I tried to set the height in `<td>` and in `<style>` like this:

```html
<table style="border-color:black;height:40%;" bgcolor="white" border="3" width="40%" height="140">
```

but it doesn't work also. I wonder why this happens and how can I fix it.

update:
Thank you for the quick responses and all the helpful update to my question yet the problem is not solved.

I change the html to what herrbischoff had suggested as follow:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="height:100%;">
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-image: url(../graphic/bg2.png);background-size:cover; font-size:1.3vw; font-family:tekton pro;height:100%; ">
    <center>
        <table style="border-color:black;height:40%;" bgcolor="white" border="3" width="40%" >
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td height="40%">
                        <center>Thank you for your participation!</center>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </center>
</body>
```

the height doesn't change, is that I miss something?

Comment: What exactly are you putting in your table that you need its height to be bigger immediately?, In your example you only have 1 column and 1 row with the text "Thank you for your participation!". If you're intention is just to have a big text with borders then just use a `div` with text inside?

Comment: All I want to put into the table is that sentence only. Since the table is the only main content on the webpage, I want it to be bigger so that the webpage won't look too empty. I tried to use <div> but is that I did something wrong?

`<div height="40%">
<table>
<tbody>
<td>
<tr>
<center>Thank you for your participation!</center>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>`

Comment: I edited my answer, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you said you needed, you don't need a table for what you want to do.

```css
#example {
  border: solid 1px black;
  max-width:50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="example">
       Thank you for your participation!
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the height doesn't change

Comment: Thx for your code! I didn't learn about div. But how should I change the height so as to make the webpage looks less empty? I inserted height inside the css you typed but it doesn't work.

Comment: It works when I set the height in px but I really want to use relative value.

Comment: @SinclairWong You can use `vh` https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp see Relative Lengths

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a table height as it is generated dynamically from the height of all rows. Also, you want to use a relative value but there's nothing to relate to. Both the `<html>` and `<body>` tags have a default height of `auto` — they grow with the content.

Therefore, you need to grow the surrounding elements explicitly. One way to do that would be as follows:

```css
html, body
{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<table style="height: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td>....</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>....</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>....</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The trick here is that you're setting both the surrounding `<html>` and `<body>` tag to a 100% height.